# Using of Local storage with the help of JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Here is my

```js
 $(".myLinks > li > a").click(function(){
  $("a.activeLink").removeClass("activeLink");
  $(this).addClass("activeLink");
 });
```

```css
.activeLink{color:red!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myLinks">
    <li id="nav1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li id="nav5"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to store last visited/ clicked link into the local storage. And when do I refresh the browser, the visited link will be shown as red colored. What will be the code for this?
[Output after storing it in local storage and browser refreshed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdDah.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Amazing people even took the time to try to help. With no code, you're just asking people to do it for you.

Comment: Hello, i have tried to addClass. This Class named activeLink. When, link1/2/3/4/5 be Clockrestaurangen IT will be in red color. Visited (colored read) link will be stored in local storage. IF the browser is refreshed IT will remain same red colored as it was previously visited.

Comment: Right.. you didn't provide any code you tried to cache them. You have more than enough helpful people here that gave you the answer. You should be able to google it and solve it yourself now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *quick and sample* snippet to work with:

```js
// Let's process when `DOM is ready`
$(document).ready(function() {

  // try-get the active item from `local storage`
  var activeLinkParentId = window.localStorage.getItem("activeLinkParentId");
  if (activeLinkParentId) {
    $("#" + activeLinkParentId + "> a").addClass("activeLink");
  }

  // Add click handler to the `anchor` tags
  $(".myLinks > li > a").click(function() {
    $("a.activeLink").removeClass("activeLink");
    window.localStorage.setItem("activeLinkParentId", $(this).parent().attr("id"));
    $(this).addClass("activeLink");
  });
});
```

```css
.activeLink {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myLinks">
  <li id="nav1">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav2">
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav3">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav4">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
  <li id="nav5">
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function to get or set local storage values

```
function setStorageItem(key, value)
{
   localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

function getStorageItem(key)
{
  return localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

and you can use it like following

```
$(".myLinks > li > a").click(function(){
        $("a.activeLink").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        setStorageItem("yourwebsitename_lastvisitedlink",$(this).attr("href"));
        setStorageItem("yourwebsitename_lastvisitedlinkID",$(this).parent("li").attr("id"));
    });
```

[check this link for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Can you please put the key and value with the required values?

Answer (score 0):

This will store a "last" key in local storage with the ID of the parent `li` for the clicked link. When they click on a link, it will overwrite whatever is in the key currently, meaning it will always reflect the last link the user clicked.

```
$(function() {
  var id = localStorage.getItem('last');
  $('#' + id).addClass('activeLink');
});

$(".myLinks > li > a").click(function(){
  /* start local storage stuff */
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  localStorage.setItem('last', id);
  /* end local storage stuff */
  $("a.activeLink").removeClass("activeLink");
  $(this).addClass("activeLink");
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code but when I refreshed the browser color didn't remain same. Visited link should be shown as red.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Coker.